# Nest elastic search.net not returning any results via any query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nest, elasticsearch-net

I've created an index in sense which I'm happy with and am trying to implement a typed query in the NEST client as follows:

1. `var node = new Uri("http://elasticsearch-blablablamrfreeman");`

   ```
       var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
           .SetTimeout(300000)
           .SetDefaultIndex("films")
           .MapDefaultTypeIndices(d => d
               .Add(typeof(film), "films"))
               .SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p=>p);
   ```
2. Inject it (amongst the searcher and indexer) with my DI:

   ```
   builder.Register(c => new ElasticClient(settings)).Named<ElasticClient>("esclient");
   ```
3. Search using any query, such as the below:

   `var result = _client.Search<film>(s => s`
       .AllIndices()
       .From(0)
       .Size(10)
       .Query(q => q
       .Term(p => p.Title, query)
       ));

The indexer seems to work fine so code not included here. I've swapped in any number of settings parameters so I know that there's some redundancy in the code set above (or at least the default index would've sufficed).

The result var contains nothing whatsoever, with a big fat 0 across all it's properties, despite my having a wealth of data across my indices (including the "films" index).

I've even tried a raw QueryRaw method with a matchall and nada!

EDIT (Chris Pratt was along the right lines here)

Running:

```
var result = _client.Search<film>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .QueryRaw(@"{ ""match_all"": {} }"));
```

And having:

```
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
            .SetTimeout(300000)
            .MapDefaultTypeIndices(d => d
                .Add(typeof (film), "chosen_index"))
            .MapDefaultTypeNames(t => t
                .Add(typeof (film), "en"));
```

Returns debug info as:

```
[Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchResponse<Nest.SearchResponse<film>>] = {StatusCode: 200, 
    Method: POST, 
    Url: http://elasticsearch-blablablamrfreeman/chosen_index/film/_search, 
    Request: {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}, 
    Response: <Response stream not captured or already read...
```

My question being: It seemed I was in fact querying the wrong URL as per Chris Pratt's comment, but why isn't the type inference working for the type but it is for the index?

/chosen_index/film/_search

should read

/chosen_index/en/_search

If my inferencing is correct.

Should it POST or GET? I usually GET via the search API on sense. And finally, what if I want to write my queries against my native film type but have it override the ES-type in the URL in some instances.

For example if I inject a different language parameter and wish to now query the same index but both "en" and "de" ES-types etc (which are all valid types under the same index as already constructed via sense).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What helps me in these scenarios is to get the actual query NEST is generating and run that against your index directly. To get the query you can debug and inspect `ConnectionStatus.Request` on your result object (it's slightly buried under `[Nest.SearchResponse<...>]` > `base`). Alternately, you can use Glimpse along with the Elasticsearch plugin to see all your queries. Based on the generated query and the raw results you get from Elasticsearch directly, you can usually determine the issue.

Comment: Also, while you're debugging, check the value of `RequestUrl` (in the same places as `Request`). If it's querying the wrong index or something, you can see instantly from that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Repied to your comments, please have a look when you can, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing obvious is jumping out at me for why this isn't working for you. However, I can give you a few avenues to pursue to attempt to resolve the issue.

1. I'm not familiar with the particular DI container that you're using, but it's possible that it's not binding properly, resulting some of your settings options not actually being utilized in the instance that's created. Might be a long shot, but I'd recommend digging in and at least verifying that the client instance you're getting is setup the way it should be.
2. It sort of side-steps the issue in a way, but Elasticsearch explicitly recommends you *don't* handle localization via different types. You should either use different indexes, i.e. `chosen_index_en`, `chosen_index_es`, etc., or use [multifields](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/using-language-analyzers.html):

   ```
   "title": {
       "type": "string",
       "fields": {
           "en": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "english"
           },
           "es": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "spanish"
           }
       }
   ```

   Then you can search on things like `title.en` or `title.es`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris, let me change my mapping structure and get back to you - hopefully with a thumbs up and many, many thank you's!

Comment: Hi chris! Sorry for the spam but please see the continuation issue for the mapping here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354226/nest-elasticsearch-net-search-query-not-returning-results-part-2

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using the default mappings for the film type. That is, the data are analyzed by the standard analyzer before being indexed.

In the query, you are using the Term query which finds documents that contain the **exact** term (not analyzed) specified in the inverted index (see [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-term-query.html)). So be careful what your *query* is.

Try to use a match query like below:

```
var result = _client.Search<film>(s => s
    .AllIndices()
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q => q
    .Match(p => p.Title, query)
));
```

The *query* is now analyzed by the standard analyzer before being applied (see [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-match-query.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately I perhaps didn't use the best query example, however I did state I used queryraw and others. I feel the issue isn't to do with my actual query - please take a look at my question edits!